# Event not firing on raspberry pi mono

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi, raspbian, sqldependency

I have been following this post for developing a client for query notification. http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/started-query-notifications-sql-server-2008-r2/1676/  I have tried this code on both visual studio and mono on my PC and these seem to fire the onDependencyChange event fine.  However when I move it over to the raspberry pi with mono-complete installed it does not seem to fire.  I cannot debug as the pi is in another location and I am using SSH to remote into it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("-----------------APPLICATION STARTED------------------");
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
        RefreshDataWithSqlDependency();

        Console.WriteLine ("Why is it here?");
        //blocks thread so you can read message
        Console.ReadLine();
        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
    }

    static void RefreshDataWithSqlDependency()
    {
        //remove existing dependency if necessary
        if (dependency != null)
        {
            dependency.OnChange -= onDependencyChange;
            dependency = null;
        }

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ipAddress FROM dbo.dbDevices", connection);

            //Create a dependency and associate it with command
            dependency = new SqlDependency(command, null, 1);

            //Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(onDependencyChange);

            //Start dependency listener
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            //execute command and refresh data
            RefreshData(command);
        }
    }

    private static void onDependencyChange(Object o, SqlNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ondep gets hit");
        if ((args.Source.ToString() == "Data") || (args.Source.ToString() == "Timeout"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Refreshing data due to {0}", args.Source);
            RefreshDataWithSqlDependency();

        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Data not refreshed due to unexpected SqlNotificationEventArgs: Source={0}, Info={1}, Type={2}", args.Source, args.Info, args.Type.ToString());
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }
    }

    private static void RefreshData(SqlCommand command)
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            Console.Clear();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ip = {0}", reader[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have now put an extra Console.WriteLine just under RefreshDataWithSqlDependency method and when I use Run > Run With > Microsoft .NET or Mono 4.0.2 it seems to jump straight out of RefreshDataWithSqlDependency, however when I run with debugger it acts as it should.  It will fire the event.

Answer (score 0):

Remote debugging would be the way to go with SSH tunneling.

On the Ras-pi side, start your app:

```
mono \
 --debug \
 --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:10000,suspend=y,server=y,keepalive=250 \
foodata.exe
```

(Yes, the address of 0.0.0.0 is correct)

On the PC side, set an environment variable to enable a hidden debug feature of Xamarian Studio / MonoDevelop and start the IDE from that cmd line.

On Linux:

```
export MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST=1 
monodevelop
```

On OS-X (with Xam Studio, alter the cmd to use MonoDevelop if that is what you have:

```
export MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST=1 
/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/XamarinStudio
```

On Windows (update the path to match your install location):

```
set MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST=1 
<path>\XamarinStudio.exe
```

Once the IDE starts, load your solution/project that you are debugging, set your breakpoints and then select the following menu items:

```
Run / Run With / Custom Command Soft Mono Debugger
```

*Note: That option will NOT be there if you you did not set the env var and run it from the cmd line.*

In the Launch Soft Debugger Window that appeared:

```
Command : ssh YourRaspiLogin@RasPiPassword -L 10000:127.0.0.1:10000 
Arguments : <leave empty>
IP : YourRasPiHostNameOrIPAddress
Port: : 10000
```

Click "Connect".

A ssh window will open, just leave it open (minimize it..), that is your reverse tunnel. If you are using some other ssh client; putty, etc..  change the 'ssh' in the command field to match your setup.

You should be debugging now and assuming you set a break point the IDE should be stopped on that line waiting for you ;-)

Comment: I have a problem when I run the application on my rpi with the debug flag, I get Cannot open assembly ' --debug' : No such file or directory

Comment: So I have solved that problem, and got to the end set a couple of breakpoints that it should definitely hit and hit connect.  I then get my SSH window however it displays, The filename, directory name or volumen label syntax is incorrect

Comment: Assuming the error is that it can not find your ssh program? Not in your path?

Comment: so when I run my application on my rpi with the debug flag, it doesnt show anything until I connect my IDE.  It then runs the application however none of the breakpoints are getting hit

Comment: No debug info (mdb?). What happens when you debug it locally (no remote connections, just running it in the IDE (and which IDE?) and get breakpoints?

Comment: Using xamarin studio, when I run with Microsoft .NET debugger it seems to fire the event fine locally, however when I run with just mono it doesn't seem to want to fire the event, and basically skips to Console.Readline().  Also when I run it locally it creates a pdb instead of an mdb?

Comment: Using Xamarin Studio, Project Options / Run / General / Run on External Console otherwise no ReadKey/Readline/.... as you have no shell to interact with.

Comment: I have edited my post to make it more clear what is happening, I have checked this already and it is checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83071/discussion-between-robertn-and-johnathon64).