# Develop in Visual Studio; run and debug on remote linux target

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, mono

I am writing a program in c# in Visual Studio, which runs on a linux target (Raspberry Pi) under the mono framework.

Is there any way of debugging the code in Visual Studio when it is running in the target machine?

Comment: Not sure about using VS for remote debugging mono, but mono to mono remote debugging works fine using Xamarin Studio; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363926/event-not-firing-on-raspberry-pi-mono/31365208#31365208

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with MonoDevelop (under Linux) and possibly with Xamarin Studio (not tested), but not with Visual Studio.

On the Raspbery Pi start the target application as follows:

```
mono --debug --debugger-agent="address=192.177.88.11:10000,transport=dt_socket,server=y" \
/full/path/to/mono-application.exe
```

Change the IP and the path to your executable. **Note** you should have a *debug* build deployed with the relevant debug files.

This adds a new menu item that allows to start a remote debugging session, under **Run -> Run With -> Custom Command Mono Soft Debugger**. This opens a dialog window; enter the IP address of your VM (192.177.88.11) and the port (10000) and start the session with the Connect button. This starts the application in the VM.

Courtesy from [remote debugging with mono](https://ebsteblog.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/remote-debugging-with-monodevelop/)
and [Debugging Remote Mono Targets](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2013/Oct-29.html)